# Polymer iron-ajax/iron-request won't fire

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to make a request using iron-ajax.

My code looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">

<iron-ajax
  id="fetch"
  url="myapi.com/resource"
  method="GET"
  content-type="application/json"
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="storeData"
  debounce-duration="300" auto>
</iron-ajax>
```

I consistently get this error and have linked to the source below.

> Uncaught TypeError: request.completes.then is not a function

https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/master/iron-ajax.html#L447

When I log the spawned `iron-request` object `request.completes` out to my console, I see the below object.

```
g
_callbacks: Object
_pendingCallbacks: Object
ctx: null
promiser: ()
__proto__ : Object
```

I am using the following versions, and `polymer serve` to run the app locally.

iron-ajax: 1.4.3
polymer: 1.7

Comment: What is the content of your event handler, namely `storeData`? Also, try to provide a minimal (non)working example.

Comment: Thanks, @alesc.  the error is the same even if storeData is simply `storeData: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
      }`

Comment: The error seems to indicate that `iron-request` is unresolved (e.g., it's not defined). Do you have a GitHub link or fiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to generate request automatically? From my experience, I use `generateRequest()` method on a given iron-ajax id, to generate the request whenever an event handler is fired (like selected change).

Comment: @alesc @tony19 this http://plnkr.co/edit/3GATdWBbiq9P0YlKHn84 shows a minimal, and unfortunately working example. The maddening thing is that it is basically boilerplate code, and `request.completes` above appears to be a valid promise AFAIK. The setter for request.completes here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/master/iron-request.html#L90

Comment: The error seems to me that `completes` is not a promise for some reason.. In what browser (and version) you were trying to run the above code? Weird thing though is that the plunker version is working for you, it should be throw an error aswell..

Comment: @DanielRadliński - agree with that diagnosis, but is the output in the original question not what a promise object would return? Chrome 55, Firefox 45.3, Safari 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awful resolution to this is that I had a naming conflict. I use `bloodhound.js` in this project and recently switched from a manually downloaded file over to bower. The `bloodhound` registered on bower is NOT the library written by twitter. It is an entirely different, one-starred, zero-forked library, last updated in 2014 that happens to overwrite the Promise prototype at a global scope :(

Thanks to all for your consideration and help!